# How do you query a database which has a variable filename?

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a sqlite database which i would like to query. However, there is a Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] error thrown when i try to read from a PHP variable.

Following are the codes ($getdb contains the file name of the db):

```
$final_db  = $getdb[2];
$db_test = new PDO ("sqlite:Database/$final_db");
$result_test = $db_test->query("SELECT * from dcerpcrequests limit 2;");
print_r($result_test);
```

thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: PDO doesn't throw exceptions unless there was a problem. Are you sure you're connecting at all in the `new PDO(...)` part?

Comment: my guess is that is where the problem lies. If i hardcode the file name there it will work. but not with the variables used by PHP :(

Comment: How do you know that the value is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Then your variable is wrong. What does `var_dump($final_db)` gives you?

Comment: sqlite doesnt seem to read php variable in their statements :(

Comment: SQLite isn't aware that there are PHP variables in the statements; in fact, it's not aware that PHP is querying it at all.

Comment: I have never used sqlite but I can guarantee you that PHP will allow you to use a variable in place of basically anything, especially in queries. Do a print(gettype($final_db));

Comment: There's usually more to PDO exception / error messages. What is the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, right under the $final_db declaration try with a var_dump($final_db) to see what the contents of the variable exactly are. If they look good, then your problem might be something else such as hidden control characters. Try sanitizing the variable using trim(), this way.

```
$final_db  = trim($getdb[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is likely to be not what you think it is. it doesn't matter if it's a variable or a hard coded value. the database server doesn't care.

Try var_dump your variables to make sure their value is what you expect it to be.

other than that it should be the working fine.